# How to construct a function from dictionary that contains function name and arguments typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function

I am having a dictionary

```
{
   "function_name":"myFunc",
   "arguments":["a1","a2"]
}
```

I want to construct a function where the function name is the function name that is present in the above dictionary (i.e myFunc ) with respective arguments (i.e ["a1","a2"]).

The final output of the generator should be:

```
myFunc(a1,a2){

}
```

Actual Usage:  I want to add this function to a class instance and invoke it

and extending this.

If this function is async then I should be able to await it.

Example:

for a smart contract to call a function we generally do (Referring to greeter smart contract )

```
contract.functions.greet().then(k => console.log(k))
```

The contract function type is:

```
 readonly functions: { [ name: string ]: ContractFunction };
 export type ContractFunction<T = any> = (...args: Array<any>) => Promise<T>;
```

using ethers library.

I wanted to generate the greet function using the contract ABI dynamically :

```
[
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_greeting",
          "type": "string"
        },
      ],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "greet",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_greeting",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "setGreeting",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ]
```

I am able to parse the above JSON and get the function name and arguments.
Now as a final step I want to attach this constructed function to the contract and call it.

Comment: And what is the function supposed to be / do?

Comment: You want to invoke that function or define it?

Comment: I want to add this function to a class instance and invoke it

Comment: @JAGADEESH Add that in your question, it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Invoking that function will not do anything, what is the point?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to do something like the following:

```js
class SomeClass {
  obj = {
    functionName: "add",
    args: [10, 20],
  };

  add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  invokeFunc() {
    const { functionName, args } = this.obj;
    return this[functionName](...args);
  }
}

const instance = new SomeClass();
console.log(instance.invokeFunc());
```

Since the function to be invoked is accessible from the `this` object, you can invoke it and [spread (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) all the arguments.

For `async` functions it's *not* clear how it's indicated that it's an `async` function. You can have a `type` field in the object and conditionally `await` the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do this.

read here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-functions-dynamically-in-javascript/
as this could help you

```js
var strFunc = [{
  "isAsync":false,
  "function_name": "myFunc",
  "arguments": ["a1", "a2"],
  content: "return a1*a2"
},
{
  "isAsync":true,
  "function_name": "asyncMyFunc",
  "arguments": ["a1", "a2"],
  content: "return a1+a2"
}]

class Funcs {
constructor(f){
const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
  f.forEach(x=> {
    let func = null;
    if (x.isAsync)
     func = new AsyncFunction(...x.arguments, x.content);
    else func = new Function(...x.arguments, x.content);
    
    this[x.function_name] = func;
  });

}

}

var mycl = new Funcs(strFunc);
mycl.asyncMyFunc(1,2).then(x=> console.log("asyncFunc", x))
console.log("syncFunc", mycl.myFunc(1,2));
```